# Path optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path

I have lot of coordinates (LatLng) that represents the path. Problem is that path is very detail, so I need to make an algorithm that simly reduse accuracy of the path. Here's my path in google maps[image]

and here's what I need. As you can see yellow line represents new less accurate path.
[image: ant here what i need]

Is there any algorithms that do what I need?

Here my own implementation, that works only on certgain situations

```
private ArrayList<LatLong> navCoordinates(ArrayList<LatLong> customRoutePoints){
        ArrayList<LatLong> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final double SHORT = 0.000321933695355628053669239108103283797390758991241455078125;
        int inc = 1;
        boolean sharp = false;
        for(int i=0; i<customRoutePoints.size(); i += inc){
            inc = 1;
            LatLong prevPoint = i - 1 >= 0 ? customRoutePoints.get(i - 1) : null;
            LatLong point = customRoutePoints.get(i);
            LatLong nextPoint = i + 1 < customRoutePoints.size() ? customRoutePoints.get(i + 1) : null;

            if(prevPoint == null){
                list.add(point);
            } else {
                if(nextPoint != null){
                    double prevDistance = prevPoint.distance(point);
                    double nextDistance = point.distance(nextPoint);
                    double angle = Math.toDegrees(angleBetweenTwoPointsWithFixedPoint(prevPoint.latitude,
                            prevPoint.longitude, nextPoint.latitude, nextPoint.longitude, point.latitude, point.longitude));

                    if (testAngle(angle)) {
                        if(prevDistance < SHORT || nextDistance < SHORT){
                            if(list.size() > 1 && !sharp){
                                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                            }
                        }
                        sharp = false;
                        inc = 2;
                        list.add(nextPoint);
                    } else {
                        list.add(point);
                        sharp = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    list.add(point);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you have the right approach, i.e. you want to remove high-frequency noise to get the low frequency features, but then you want to keep sharp edges (very high frequencies). Maybe you want to start by doing some smoothing on the input path, but if your code doesn't work as expected, you need to add some more debugging infos like the current output or where it breaks, SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: I especially like the exorbitant precision you computed for the `SHORT` distance: [more precise than reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) ;-)